# What do you call data that is to be processed by a template engine?

Tags: templates

I haven't found any good terms for data (or files) that is to be feeded by a template engine. I've frequently heard this data called "template" itself, but that's obviously a misnomer (a template is the processing instructions, not the data processed upon). Wikipedia says "document" in some places, but that's not general enough.

This is the first time I regret I'm not using XML, because XML has more or less implicit that
it is being processed to another representation.

Answer (score 1):

What about "template arguments" or "template parameters"? Technically, it would fit: a template is a set function (algorithm), whose output depends solely on its input. The name would be analogical to mathematical functions, which work more or less on the same principle.

Comment: Templates are not functions or algorithms (otherwise they would be called functions). A template is scaffolding. Templates may _contain_ functions, but that's specific to that template language/interpreter. For example, string templates don't have any logic.

Comment: I think that it could still be interpreted as such - using your string template example, it would be the simplest function of just taking the input (or, in your terminology, _context_ containing the string to be processed) and just outputting that, without any change.

Answer (score 0):

The term most commonly used is *context*. A template is processed with a context, which contains the variables that are to be interpreted for the template.

If the context changes, the output rendered by the template changes as well.

Terms like "payload" are also used, but this is more of a network term and not generic enough for templates.